# Custom Error Pages for django-cms

Tags: django, django-cms

Supposedly a trivial task to server 403/404/500 error pages when using django-cms. Followed instructions on an old forum post to create this:

```
from cms.views import details

def custom_404(request):
    response = details(request, 'page-not-found')
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
...
```

Urls.py has some lines like this:

```
handler404 = 'error_pages.views.custom_404'
...
```

From traceback django cms can't locate 404 page:

```
File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/views.py", line 22, in _handle_no_page
    raise Http404('CMS: Page not found for "%s"' % slug)

Http404: CMS: Page not found for "page-not-found"
```

Obviously added the required custom pages in django-cms with the slug: 'page-not-found'. Am I missing something obvious? Running on production server with `debug=False`. Running django-cms 2.4.2 (edit)

Perhaps it is better to just serve plain ol' error messages with hardcoded stylesheets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After walking into countless walls over-thinking the issues, I just went with using the basic 403/404/500 handlers:

```
from django.utils.functional import curry
from django.views.defaults import *
handler500 = curry(server_error, template_name='500.html')
handler404 = curry(page_not_found, template_name='404.html')
handler403 = curry(permission_denied, template_name='403.html')
```

Created the templates for each error and put in absolute URLs for the stylesheets.

Problem solved. Wasted a bunch of time on something this trivial.

Comment: actually, there is a real solution for your original question. even two of them, an old one, that would have worked when your question was asked (as I was updating a legacy system), and a super easy, django-cms > 3.0 version. I think it's worth having a "404 that is easily editable through the cms by your users/editors"...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working (with DEBUG at True or False) 404 handler:

```
def handler404(request):
    if hasattr(request, '_current_page_cache'):
        delattr(request, '_current_page_cache')

    response = details(request, '404')
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

Comment: actually this resolution works. BUT note that you'll have to 'return response.render()' in oder to get the page

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT / Easy solution**

After more searching and thinking, an easier solution would be to create the default/standard 404.html, and therein use django-cms static placeholders...as easy as it gets!

**Original (still working) Answer**

After struggling updating my handler404 from an old cms project, and not finding any infos on this topic, and the accepted answer not being a real solution to the problem, I investigated and found a version that works in django-cms 3.4.

**Worth noting**

- delete the `_current_page_cache` on the request
- set `request.current_page`, or `cms_tags` will not use your 404 page and render empty
- call the main cms `details` view for rendering the page
- finally, call `response.render()` (as mentioned in comments)

**The view**

```
def handler404(request):
    if hasattr(request, '_current_page_cache'):  # we'll hit the cache otherwise
        delattr(request, '_current_page_cache')
    page = get_page_from_request(request, '404')
    request.current_page = page  # templatags seem to use this.
    response = details(request, '404')  # the main cms view
    if hasattr(response, 'render'):  # 301/302 dont have it!
        response.render()  # didnt know about this, but it's needed
    response.status_code = 404  # the obvious
    return response
```